# MongoDB Atlas connection not working on Heroku for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I keep receiving this error on Heroku:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

I have already added 0.0.0.0 and my own IP address to Atlas.

This is how I am connecting (using Mongoose):

```js
// link mongoose
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_LINK, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});
```

I have already added the DB_LINK to a config variable on Heroku.

Everything works great on localhost. I'm unsure as to why this does not work. I also get this error at the end:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I haven't used Atlas + Heroku but IME the most common cause of a DB connection timing out is a security rule at the network layer. You say you've added 0.0.0.0 and your own IP address to Atlas, so it makes sense that it would work from your local machine, but have you figured out how to add whichever domains/IP range Heroku would be using to connect to Atlas?

Comment: @JimJ I had thought that 0.0.0.0 would allow any IP to join (because that it what is inputted when I selected to allow all IPs on Atlas). Other answers on Stack Overflow also say to allow 0.0.0.0 but it did not work for me.

Comment: OK, I looked up the Atlas documentation and it says that a both specific IP (like `0.0.0.0`) and a CIDR range of addresses (`0.0.0.0/0`) are acceptable for security rules. One way to determine if "allow any IP to join" is actually true is to remove your specific local IP address, and then try connecting from your local machine. Have you tried that?

Comment: @JimJ Thanks for looking into this. It does work on localhost when I remove my own IP, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I guess I just had to give it time. Thanks!

Comment: Can u share to us how you did that? I'm now facing the same problem right now

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'll give more detailed answer as described in @Jack comment section.

**1. Go to the Network Access section**
[image]

**2. Click `add IP address` button on the right section**
[image]

**3. Click allow access from anywhere.**
[image]